# C# - mysql ExecuteNonQuery suddenly crashing

Tags: c#, mysql

So my C# code suddenly started to give me an error when I want to do `storeData.ExecuteNonQuery`

here is my code:

```
string conString = @"Data Source=someip; Port=3306; Initial Catalog=SalesKicker; User ID=Root; Password=hurrdurr;Integrated Security=true;";
MySqlConnection SalesKicker;
SalesKicker = new MySqlConnection(conString);

SalesKicker.Open();

MySqlCommand storeData = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO SalesKicker (BedrijfsName, ContPers, TelNum, e-mail, Land, Plaats, PostCode)" + "VALUES (@BedrijfsNaam, @ContPers, @TelNum, @e-mail, @Land, @Plaats, @PostCode)", SalesKicker);

                try {
                    storeData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BedrijfsNaam", txxBvName.Text);
                    storeData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContPers", txxContPersn.Text);
                    storeData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelNum", Convert.ToInt32(txxTelNr.Text));
                    storeData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e-mail", txxEMail.Text);
                    storeData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Land", txxLand.Text);
                    storeData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Plaats", txxPlaats.Text);
                    storeData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", txxPostCode.Text);
                } catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Er zijn ongeldige gegevens ingevoerd!");
                }
                storeData.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SalesKicker.Close();
                this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Doelen());
```

This worked fine before but now it suddenly gives me this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

This code seriously worked before, something must have changed in the mean time but what?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [ PostCode)" + "VALUES ] - probably you are missing space before VALUES.

Comment: It is not "crashing", it is throwing an exception. The first reaction to a runtime exception should not be to post it on Stack Overflow. Click _"View Detail..."_, view the InnerException for the actual exception and research that. Besides, phone numbers aren't integers. I'm also quite sure that you can't have hyphens in unescaped identifiers (`e-mail`).

Comment: you are right, thanks for the answer

Comment: Also worth noting that MySQL's exception handling are... faulty at best. All of their exceptions (until 5.1, at least. Dunno if they improved it in the latest versions) throw the same "Fatal error encountered" message.

Comment: May be missing some values..Do you change anything in client?